# Object reference across beans

Tags: java, object, ejb, pass-by-reference

Today I came across one situation, here it is.

I have a db object to persist. I use `SampleBean.add` method. Inside that method, I'm getting primary key from a sequence, setting it to db object's id property and persisting it to db (using `PreparedStatement`). But I could not get the db object's id property (it comes as 0, even though it got set in persisting method) from the method I'am calling that bean method.

Please clarify me this.

DB Object

```
public class LogRow implements Serializable {
     public long cardLogId;
     public String data;
}
```

Persist method

```
public void insertLogRow(LogRow logRow) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;        
        try {
            String insertSql = LogRow.INSERT_LOG;
            con = global.getConnection();
            if (logger.isEnabled(IMessage.DEBUG1)) {
                logger.println(IMessage.DEBUG1, CLASS_NAME + "insertLogRow():: insertSql " + insertSql);
            }
            ps = con.prepareStatement(insertSql);
            logRow.setLogId(seq.getNextVal());
            ps.executeUpdate(); 
        } catch (SQLException sqe) {          
            logger.println("insertLogRow():: SQLException occurred");
            throw new ProcessingErrorException(sqe.getMessage());
        } 
}
```

I am able to see the persisted id value here in persist method.

Calling method

```
RemoteLookup.getSampleBean().insertLogRow(logRow);
log.println("log id " + logRow.logId());
```

This calling method prints `0`

Comment: Can you show some code?  I can't quite parse the sentence about the "newly created primary key".  Can you edit your question and flesh that out?

Comment: @Gray I have updated, can you please check now?

Comment: @Vanathi, please show us some code

Comment: I still don't understand.  Are you saying that you are not able to get the value from the sequence?  Or you are trying to insert an object with an id generated by the database and you can't get the generated id from JDBC?  Can you show some code?

Comment: @Vanathi, please look at my answer and clarify if thats your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is not an Answer:***
Since the question is very difficult to understand I have tried to rephrase it, cant edit the question without understanding it.

I have an object say `User` to be saved in database, In my `SampleBean.add` method I fetch the id by getting the next val of some sequence say `userSequence`.

The same value (fetched from `userSequence` is set as the id of User object.

Now while persisting the object I am not getting the value of id which I have already set in `SampleBean.add` method.

For Persistence I am using `PreparedStatement`. Can you help me in understanding why is this happening ?

***This part is Answer***

Your are doing a RemoteLookup, and in Java Remote objects are not sent given copy instead it serializes it and sends it, if you want to see the changes done to your object in remove service then you will have to send your object back

So the code changes required:

1. Change your `insertLogRow` method and make it return the object which it has persisted like:

   ```
     public LogRow insertLogRow(LogRow logRow) {
        //Do all database operation
        return logRow;
     }
   ```
2. Now change the caller code:

   ```
    logRow = RemoteLookup.getSampleBean().insertLogRow(logRow);
    log.println("log id " + logRow.logId());
   ```

Rebuild, deploy and run.

Now you should see your id which has been set on the object inside insertLogRow method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, But I am able to see the id value in add method. I am not able to see the same in calling method, which got set in persisting method

Comment: yes, I changed like that and worked. But wanted to know the reason behind it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vanathi Glad to be of help :), you may want to read this : http://oreilly.com/catalog/javarmi/chapter/ch10.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are missing a `setLong(1, logRow.getCardLogId())` call after you build your prepared statement.  I assume the statement is something like:

```
INSERT into LogRow (cardLogId, data) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Then you need to set the values for the `?` arguments:

```
ps.setLong(1, logRow.getCardLogId());
ps.setString(2, logRow.getData());
```

But maybe the object is some sort of magic EJB proxy that does the database update itself?